# Lightswitch unique to an entity

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

In my Lightswitch project, I have an People table with 1 to many relationship to Emails table.  This is very similar to what Beth Massi did in her LS walkthrough at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2013/10/23/beginning-lightswitch-in-vs-2013-part-2-feel-the-love-defining-data-relationships.aspx. Each email address has an emailType (i.e. Work, Personal, Other).  How do I limit each user to only one email per emailType?

Beth uses a Choice List..I tend to always create a relationship to another table so it's all visible from SQL.  Either way, a user is able to add multiple "work" emails.  If you set EmailType to be Unique, that's applied across the board and now you can only have one Work email system wide rather than one Work email per person.

I hit this same issue with Accounts and Phones where each Account should only have one Primary or one Fax phonetype.

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 2):

You could add the emailType and email to the unique index of the table.  That will ensure that each user has a unique emailType/email combination.  To do this.  Open up the entity and, for each field you want to add to the unique index, check the "Include in Unique Index" checkbox.

Comment: Thanks.  The key was as you mentioned to make both the EmailType to Email unique and the Account to Email unique.  I was just adding one which made it unique across everything.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to add a CHECK constraint to the tables concerned that invalidates the record if the count of EmailType, AccountType, etc.  Entity Framework will throw Check Constraint errors back up to the app if you need that kind of validation logic.